# Win7 on eeePc 1008HA. How to have SHE and hotkey services run on startup?

Tags: windows-7, services, eee-pc

I've got everything running on my eeePc.
Win 7 Pro and the latest versions of the respective tools.

Unfortunately when i installed them they didnt add the services to autostart.
After booting I can manually start them and everything works fine (after UAC confirmation).

My question is: How can I start these services without UAC on startup?

Answer (score 0):

Well, to make them start with Windows, add shortcuts to this folder: `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. Next you'll have to set those to run with elevated privileges:

1. Right-click on the shortcut.
2. Click **Properties**, and then select the **Compatibility** tab.
3. Under **Privilege Level**, select **Run this program as an administrator**,
   and then click OK.

Do that for each shortcut and you shouldn't get the UAC prompt anymore.

Comment: Doesn't that do the exact opposite? If i run sth as an administrator, it will always prompt for the UAC confirmation. Even if it didnt do so before.